# Where can i find gta 5 saves on xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I have a problem finding my saves in the file manager, any ideas where they can be?

Answer (score -1):

Pause the game and go over to game.Go down to load game and your save files will be there.I have an xbox one,but I have played it on xbox 360 before.

Comment: I believe the question is asking where in the file system are the saves stored, not how to access them in-game.